# Locate text position in TextView

Tags: android, textview

How can I calculate the position X , Y of a letter in a `TextView` by knowing it's index?
I need this to show a graphical pointer to the touched letter or word but I don't know how to locate the right place.

Comment: if you know the index, then maybe x = (Paint.measureText(yourText) / yourText.length()) * index

Comment: is it a one-line TextView or can be more than one line?

Comment: It's big TextView with so many lines ;)

Comment: y = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325798/android-textview-and-getting-line-of-text

Comment: This is a good question. Shoudnt have been marked negative. Let me know if anybody get an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you:

I am not aware of a simple direct way to do this but you should be able to put something together using the Paint object of the `TextView` via a call to `TextView.getPaint()..`

Once you have the paint object you will have access to the underlying `FontMetrices` via a call to `Paint.getFontMetrics()` and have access to other functions like `Paint.measureText()` `Paint.getTextBounds()`, and `Paint.getTextWidths()` for accessing the actual size of the displayed text...

Comment: It sounds helpful , Thx

Comment: sure , let me give a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),bounds);
int height = bounds.height();
int width = bounds.width();
```

That should give you the height and width. Create an array of height/widths with a different value for each individual character, you could do it quickly if you used a loop and ASCII character codes. Then, you could add the widths of each character until you get to the one you want.

But there's what I think is an easier way. Instead of a TextView, try a LinearLayout with multiple textviews. If you use a textview for each character, you can just use getX and getY.