# Get access to the beginning of the second line in TextView

Tags: java, android, string

There is a String, which in TextView automatically transfers words to the second line because of the large number of words in one line. I would like to access the beginning of the second line for further editing.

I tried to check for "\n", but it did not work.

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325798/android-textview-and-getting-line-of-text

Comment: @P.Juni you're right. Add this in the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: It’s not an answer, it’s just copy pasted of already given answer, so i wont put it as mine own :) but you are welcome